# dateadd_holidays in snowflake

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a function that evaluates if dateadd(day,x,date) is a holiday or a satyurday or a sunday and if it is, add 1 day to x until i get a business day. I have a table with the holidays

I imagine something like this but is not running

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adjust_date_for_holiday(date_to_adjust DATE, days_to_add INT)
  RETURNS DATE
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  begin
    declare looper int default 0;
    while looper>0 do
      if day_of_week(dateadd(day,days_to_add+looper,date_to_adjust)) in (1,7) or EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HOLIDAYS_COL WHERE holiday_date = dateadd(day,days_to_add+looper,date_to_adjust)) then
        looper:=looper+1;
      else 
        looper:=-1;
      end if;
    end while;
    return dateadd(day,days_to_add+looper,date_to_adjust);
  end;
;
```

Comment: When you say it's not running, does that mean you're getting an error or a bad result?  Could you share that information?  A couple of quick notes, though. `day_of_week` should be `dayofweek` in Snowflake.  And 1 is Monday on my account, so double-check that you have the right values there.  You are also setting looper to 0 and then the while loop has while > 0.  So, the loop will never get executed.